# Python Kivy: Add Background loop

Tags: android, python, infinite-loop, kivy

I want to paste a background loop into my Python-Kivy script. The problem is, that I've got only a `App().run()` under my script. So, if I put a loop, somewhere in the the App-Class, the whole App stopps updating and checking for events. Is there a function name like `build(self)`, that's recognized by Kivy, and represents a main/background-loop?

*If you don't know, what I'm talking about, feel free to ask.*

Comment: If you need to schedule a repeated activity in a loop, you can use `Clock.schedule_interval()` to call a function on a regular schedule. More information about Events in Kivy [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html).

Comment: That's it - answer below, and I can vote for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you need to schedule a repeated activity in a loop, you can use `Clock.schedule_interval()` to call a function on a regular schedule:

```
def my_repeated_function(data):
    print ("My function called.")

Clock.schedule_interval(my_repeated_function, 1.0 / 30) # no brackets on function reference 
                                                       # call it 30 times per second
```

There is a lot more information on how to schedule events on a regular, conditional or one-time basis with Kivy's event loop [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html).